# Outputting weirdly large number in C++

Tags: c++, function, vector

Hey new to C++ and working on a simple problem that takes a sequence of Int's and outputs the sum of the numbers without the smallest and largest number.

If the vector has one or no elements then it is to return 0.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int test(vector<int> numbers) {

  typedef vector<int>::size_type vec_sz;
  vec_sz size = numbers.size();


  if (size <= 1) {
    cout << "Vector less than 2" << endl;
    return 0;
  } else {
    sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

    int answer;
    for (int i=1; i < size-1; i++) {
        answer += numbers[i];
    }
    return answer;

  }

}

int main() {
    vector<int> vec = {2,1,3,4,6,5,7,9,8,10};
    cout << test(vec) << endl;

    vector<int> vec_2 = {1};
    cout << test(vec_2) << endl;

}
```

When I run this I get something along the lines of:

```
3829804
Vector less than 2
0
```

Why am I getting an absurdly large number when the vector is > 1, when it is just supposed to be returning the sum of 2-8?

When I make the program without the checking for the vector with 1 or less items I have no problem. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Local variables (like `answer` in your function) are by default *uninitialized*. Their values are *indeterminate* (and seemingly random). Using such variables without initialization leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: ..... so change  `int answer` to `int answer = 0`.   Or, better yet, replace the whole logic with `answer` and adding the values in a loop, and instead `return std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0)`

Comment: You should turn on your compiler's warnings, which would have pointed out the problem.

Comment: @Peter - did you mean `std::accumulate(numbers.begin()+1, numbers.end()-1, 0)`?  Since the first and last must be excluded.  (Better still would be to skip all the storing and sorting, and simply subtract the min and max from the rolling sum at the end of input).

Answer (score 4):

`answer` is **not** initialized in your function and will have *indeterminate* value.
Any usage will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#Uninitialized_scalar).

```
int answer; // uninitialized
            // answer will have indeterminate value
for (int i=1; i < size-1; i++) {
    answer += numbers[i]; // undefined behavior
}
return answer;
```

As per [dcl.init/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#12):

> If **no** initializer is specified for an object, the object is *default-initialized*.
>   When storage for an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration
>   is obtained, the object has an **indeterminate** value,

So just initialize `answer`:

```
int answer = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making answer set to 0 before the for for loop. This should fix the problem since the APU is trying to add a number to an undefined number.